# How can I restrict the setter to three options?

Tags: java

I mean, I'm right know trying to generate a setter for following atributes for a "Car" class

```
private String model;
private String color;
private String brightPainting; //Yes or Not
private String carPlate;
private String carKind; //litle car, family car, sport car
```

The thing is that I want to generate the getters a setters for the atributes but I want to know if does exist the possibility of restrict the setter for `brightPainting` to just be "yes" or "no" and also for `carKind`, to be 3 option **litle car**, **family car** or **sport car**.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use a boolean for the brightPainting field (not a String). Use an enum for the carKing field (not a String).

Comment: Use other data types than just `String`.  You can use a `Boolean`, an `enum`, custom types, etc.  Or, if you really want *everything* to be a string, you could put logic in the setter which examines the input and throws an exception if it doesn't match the expected values.

Answer (score 2):

for yes or no you have [boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) data type use it

and for the carKind [use Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, It was very simple tho.